# Why do false statements print nothing rather than 0 in PHP?

Tags: php

Here's a simple example:

```
echo 3==3; // echoes 1

echo 3==2; // should echo 0, yet echoes nothing
```

I noticed this as I was designing a form which entails a checkbox. When ticked, the checkbox passes a value of 1, when unticked, rather than passing a value of 0 as one would expect, it passes nothing; an undefined boolean so to speak.

I tried solving this with the following code:

```
$myBool = isset($_POST['myCheckbox']);
```

However, this doesn't seem to work either.

One solution to passing the checkbox value to `$myBool` would be to do some if-else conditioning, but I want a more concise solution. Is this possible?

Comment: To answer the second part, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268887/how-do-i-see-which-checkbox-is-checked

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, every decision makes statement returns a boolean value, either true or false. So, `echo 3==3;` is a true statement, That's why it returns 1 and `echo 3==2;` is a false statement, that's why it returns nothing.

But if you want to echo out the associated integer of false (which is 0), then you can use typecasting. Like:

```
echo (int)(3 == 2);
```

It will print out 0.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `3 == 2` evaluates to false, and as noted in the PHP documentation for [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) under the examples section, running `echo false` won't print anything because it's not technically a function. However, you can use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) instead.

```
echo 3 == 2; // no output
echo false; // no output

var_dump(3 == 2); // outputs bool(false)
var_dump(false); // outputs bool(false)
```

Comment: "running `echo false` won't print anything because it's not technically a function": that's not the reason, and that's not what the documentation you linked to says either.

Comment: @DecentDabbler At the top of the echo documentation it says “echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct)” and later says in a comment under the examples section that “because echo does not behave like a function, the following code is invalid”

Comment: But that example does not illustrate the same problem as OP's problem at all. That example is about using `echo` in a ternary expression ( `expression to evaluate ? if true expression : if false expression` ). It's a totally different issue.

Answer (score 1):

The actual reason for your question about why a statement that evaluates to `echo false;` prints an empty string, is given in [the documentation on strings](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), in the [section about casting to string](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting):

> ### Converting to string
>
> ---
>
> A value can be converted to a string using the (string) cast or the
>   strval() function. **String conversion is automatically done in the
>   scope of an expression where a string is needed. This happens when
>   using the echo or print functions, or when a variable is compared to a
>   string.** The sections on Types and Type Juggling will make the
>   following clearer. See also the settype() function.
>
> A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". **Boolean FALSE
>   is converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and
>   forth between boolean and string values.**

---

The reason that you can't test an unchecked checkbox, the way you tried, is that browsers don't send unchecked checkbox states on form submissions.

Typical solutions to this conundrum are:

1. Keep track of all available checkboxes in the backend and compare them upon receiving a form submission.
2. Add a hidden field in your HTML form *before* the actual checkbox, giving it the same name as the checkbox and a value that represents the unchecked state.

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="checkbox1" value="0">
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="1">
   ```

   These hidden fields *will* be submitted upon form submission and will be overwritten by the checkbox value if it is checked<sup>1</sup>.

   ---

   <sup>1) The values will actually both be send if the checkbox is checked, but PHP will overwrite any earlier received value with a later received value if they have the same parameter name (unless the parameter name represents an array without explicit key names, like `name="checkbox[]"` instead of `name="checkbox[1]"`).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Test Code

```
// http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

echo 3==3;

echo "<br>---------------<br>";

echo 3==2;

echo "<br>---------------<br>";

var_dump(3==3);

echo "<br>---------------<br>";

var_dump(3==2);
```

Output

```
1
---------------

---------------

boolean true


---------------

boolean false
```

The reason is for no output is you are trying to echo the boolean "false", which prints nothing.

Comment: You are basically reiterating OP's own observation without explaining *why* `echo`-ing a boolean `false` prints an empty string, instead of `0`.

Comment: I assumed he thought it was incorrect behavour. With the var dumps you can see it is correctly assigned false, but prints nothing. It is the intended behaviour.

Comment: But your right, I should have also quoted documentation as others had done.

Comment: Okay, I see where you are coming from now. By the way, I don't necessarily think quoting documentation was necessary; I just thought OP could do with a little more explanation as to why `echo false;` behaves the way it does.

Comment: Yeah I can see that. I'll store it in my brain for next time.